# Question regarding MOSFET driver

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, pwm, mosfet-driver

I'm going through the datasheet of this MOSFET driver IC - [MIC5021](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005677A.pdf) to understand the pins and the terms better.

In the first page, it is mentioned as, The MIC5021 high-side MOSFET driver is designed to
operate at frequencies up to 100 kHz (5 kHz PWM for 2% to 100% duty cycle)"

I want to understand if this 100kHz is given at the TTL pin of the IC or does it come as the output pin - the GATE pin?
If not, what is the input given to the TTL pin? Is it PWM?
Also, if the 5kHz PWM is 2% duty, then 100% duty would be 250kHz right? But it is mentioned as the drive is designed to operate at frequencies upto only 100kHz? How to understand this?

Comment: *if the 5kHz PWM is 2% duty, then 100% duty would be 250kHz right?* - no. You can have 2% duty cycle at 5kHz and at 100kHz, the difference would be that for 5kHz the high pulse length will be (1/5000*0.02) 4 micro seconds and for 100 kHz it will be (1/100000*0.02) 200 nano seconds. Respectively for 100% duty cycle you will have the entire period at high, or in other words there will be no pulse, thus no frequency.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification@php_nub_qq. So, this PWM input is given at the TTL pin right? And the same PWM frequency is replicated at the GATE pin of the IC? Is my understanding right?

Comment: I would assume so. I've only worked with one MOSFET driver, I don't have that much experience. Looking at the **Functional Block Diagram** yours seem to be a little more complicated and as far as I can see there's a NOR gate on the inverted input, so Ct must be low in order for the output (Gate) to be high. I could be wrong though.